# Verificar em uma tabela se um usuário não está cadastrado

Tags: sql, sql-select

Colegas,

tenho uma tabela chamada salas_usuarios, essa tabela contém todos os usuários cadastrados nas salas e uma outra tabela chamada usuarios, onde armazeno os usuários. Porém gostaria de verificar quais os usuários não estão cadastrados em uma determinada sala. A query que estou usando é a seguinte:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios USU
INNER JOIN sala_usuarios SAL ON USU.id_usuario != SALA.codigo_usuario_fk
INNER JOIN predio PRE ON PRE.codigo_predio = SAL.codigo_predio_fk
WHERE SALA.codigo_sala =93
GROUP BY USU.id_usuario
```

Só que lista todos os usuários e não só da sala 93

Comment: Só não se esqueça de usar corretamente o ALIAS, você definiu como SAL mas está usando SALA. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira é essa:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios USU
LEFT JOIN sala_usuarios SALA ON USU.id_usuario = SALA.codigo_usuario_fk
WHERE SALA.codigo_sala = 93
and USU.id_usuario is null
```

Retirei o *join* com `predio`, pois é irrelevante pra esse contexto.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo como:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM usuarios USU
INNER JOIN sala_usuarios SALA ON USU.id_usuario = SALA.codigo_usuario_fk
INNER JOIN predio PRE ON PRE.codigo_predio = SAL.codigo_predio_fk
WHERE USU.id_usuario not in (select distinct codigo_usuario_fk from sala_usuarios where codigo_sala = 93)
GROUP BY USU.id_usuario
```